# MAX30003 using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am doing project on Single-lead ECG & Heart rate Variability using MAX30003 using Arduino.  I have added the code for this project also. Can anyone please tell me how to include Timer.h library. I am getting following error:

> F:\TRACKER WAVE\MAX INT\max
>   ard\Protocentral-protocentral_max30003-v0.1-12-ge141d22
>   (1)\Protocentral-protocentral_max30003-e141d22\software\protocentral_max30003_arduino\protocentral_max30003\protocentral_max30003.ino:34:22:
>   fatal error: TimerOne.h: No such file or directory
>
> #include
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

The code is here:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include "MAX30003.h"

#define MAX30003_CS_PIN   7
#define CLK_PIN          6

volatile char SPI_RX_Buff[5] ;
volatile char *SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr;
int i=0;
unsigned long uintECGraw = 0;
signed long intECGraw=0;
uint8_t DataPacketHeader[20];
uint8_t data_len = 8;
signed long ecgdata;
unsigned long data;

char SPI_temp_32b[4];
char SPI_temp_Burst[100];

// 32KHz clock using timer1
void timerIsr()
{
    digitalWrite( CLK_PIN, digitalRead(CLK_PIN ) ^ 1 ); // toggle Digital6 attached to FCLK  of MAX30003
}

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200); //Serial begin

    pinMode(MAX30003_CS_PIN,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN,HIGH); //disable device

    SPI.begin();
    SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST); 
    SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);

  //please enable the below lines if you are using older version of Protocentral_max30003 board without 32k f-clock generator
    /*SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
    pinMode(CLK_PIN,OUTPUT);

     //Start CLK timer
    Timer1.initialize(16);              // set a timer of length 100000 microseconds (or 0.1 sec - or 10Hz => the led will blink 5 times, 5 cycles of on-and-off, per second)
    Timer1.attachInterrupt( timerIsr ); // attach the service routine here
*/
    MAX30003_begin();   // initialize MAX30003 
}

void loop() 
{
    MAX30003_Reg_Read(ECG_FIFO);

    unsigned long data0 = (unsigned long) (SPI_temp_32b[0]);
    data0 = data0 <<24;
    unsigned long data1 = (unsigned long) (SPI_temp_32b[1]);
    data1 = data1 <<16;
    unsigned long data2 = (unsigned long) (SPI_temp_32b[2]);
    data2 = data2 >>6;
    data2 = data2 & 0x03;

    data = (unsigned long) (data0 | data1 | data2);
    ecgdata = (signed long) (data);

    MAX30003_Reg_Read(RTOR);
    unsigned long RTOR_msb = (unsigned long) (SPI_temp_32b[0]);
   // RTOR_msb = RTOR_msb <<8;
    unsigned char RTOR_lsb = (unsigned char) (SPI_temp_32b[1]);

    unsigned long rtor = (RTOR_msb<<8 | RTOR_lsb);
    rtor = ((rtor >>2) & 0x3fff) ;

    float hr =  60 /((float)rtor*0.008); 
    unsigned int HR = (unsigned int)hr;  // type cast to int

    unsigned int RR = (unsigned int)rtor*8 ;  //8ms

     /*Serial.print(RTOR_msb);
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.print(RTOR_lsb);
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.print(rtor); 
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.print(rr);
     Serial.print(",");
     Serial.println(hr);      */

      DataPacketHeader[0] = 0x0A;
      DataPacketHeader[1] = 0xFA;
      DataPacketHeader[2] = 0x0C;
      DataPacketHeader[3] = 0;
      DataPacketHeader[4] = 0x02;

      DataPacketHeader[5] = ecgdata;
      DataPacketHeader[6] = ecgdata>>8;
      DataPacketHeader[7] = ecgdata>>16;
      DataPacketHeader[8] = ecgdata>>24; 

      DataPacketHeader[9] =  RR ;
      DataPacketHeader[10] = RR >>8;
      DataPacketHeader[11] = 0x00;
      DataPacketHeader[12] = 0x00; 

      DataPacketHeader[13] = HR ;
      DataPacketHeader[14] = HR >>8;
      DataPacketHeader[15] = 0x00;
      DataPacketHeader[16] = 0x00; 

      DataPacketHeader[17] = 0x00;
      DataPacketHeader[18] = 0x0b;

      for(i=0; i<19; i++) // transmit the data
      {
        Serial.write(DataPacketHeader[i]);

       }    

    delay(8);      
}

void MAX30003_Reg_Write (unsigned char WRITE_ADDRESS, unsigned long data)
{

    // now combine the register address and the command into one byte:
     byte dataToSend = (WRITE_ADDRESS<<1) | WREG;

     // take the chip select low to select the device:
     digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, LOW);

     delay(2);
     SPI.transfer(dataToSend);   //Send register location
     SPI.transfer(data>>16);     //number of register to wr
     SPI.transfer(data>>8);      //number of register to wr
     SPI.transfer(data);      //Send value to record into register
     delay(2);

     // take the chip select high to de-select:
     digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

void max30003_sw_reset(void)
{
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(SW_RST,0x000000);     
    delay(100);
}

void max30003_synch(void)
{
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(SYNCH,0x000000);
}

void MAX30003_Reg_Read(uint8_t Reg_address)
{
    uint8_t SPI_TX_Buff;

    digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, LOW);

    SPI_TX_Buff = (Reg_address<<1 ) | RREG;
    SPI.transfer(SPI_TX_Buff); //Send register location

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       SPI_temp_32b[i] = SPI.transfer(0xff);
    }

    digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

void MAX30003_Read_Data(int num_samples)
{
    uint8_t SPI_TX_Buff;

    digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, LOW);   

    SPI_TX_Buff = (ECG_FIFO_BURST<<1 ) | RREG;
    SPI.transfer(SPI_TX_Buff); //Send register location

    for ( i = 0; i < num_samples*3; ++i)
    {
      SPI_temp_Burst[i] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    }

    digitalWrite(MAX30003_CS_PIN, HIGH);  
}

void MAX30003_begin()
{    
    max30003_sw_reset();
    delay(100);
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(CNFG_GEN, 0x081007);
    delay(100);
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(CNFG_CAL, 0x720000);  // 0x700000  
    delay(100);
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(CNFG_EMUX,0x0B0000);
    delay(100);
    MAX30003_Reg_Write(CNFG_ECG, 0x805000);  // d23 - d22 : 10 for 250sps , 00:500 sps
    delay(100);

    MAX30003_Reg_Write(CNFG_RTOR1,0x3fc600);
    max30003_synch();
    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: some parts of your code are properly formatted ..  the rest is not ... why are you not asking how to format the code?

Comment: Nowadays, the Arduino IDE has a Library Manager helping to properly install and add libraries to projects. Perhaps you remove TimerOne manually and add it again using that tool. (Manager, then Sketch -> include Library )